# WiFi Direct Chat Group Owner

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct, wifip2p

Im trying to make a chat with wifi direct in android. But i have some question. Suppose that there are 10 devices in a room. To make it comunicate i must have 1 group owner and 9 client right? So, if i am a client, how do i find the group owner to connect to him? How do i know if there is a group owner in the room? I tried to make a connection and i have make comunication 3 device but manually. I would like to find a group owner in a room and connect to it. I tried also to rename a device in "GroupOwner" but is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using WiFiP2PManager you will be able to scan for group owners and get the list, just like scanning for WiFi AP. You can also send connection request to one of them. All these can be done programmably. Android 4.1 also provides sample codes for WiFi-direct:

http://www.androidside.com/docs/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html

Comment: I Precise. I would like to know the group owner without making connections.

Comment: It's in the onClick function of DeviceDetailFragment class.

Comment: You may try requestConnectionInfo and requestGroupInfo in WiFiP2PManager to see if they provide group owner info.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i know if there is a group owner in the room?

Well once you get the list of peers in the `onPeersAvailable` callback you can call

```
WifiP2pDevice groupOwner = null;
Collection<WifiP2pDevice> deviceList = peerList.getDeviceList();
ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
peers.addAll(deviceList);
int i = 0 ;
while(i < peers.size() && groupOwner ==null){
    if(peers.get(i).isGroupOwner() == true){
        groupOwner = peers.get(i);
    }
    i =i+1 ;
}
```

I hope this helps finding your Group Owner.